# custom jquery validation with php session value in rule

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I have created a system to print pdf's. It is based on a sort of shopping cart. Select the pdf, choose how many times, you want to print the pdf (1-10). In the print queue (shopping cart) you can click a button and in 1 input field enter a comma seperated string with names with maximum the number of prints. Each pdf wil then be printed with the name of the user. If there are less names than the number of prints the remaining prints are printed without name. I need a sort of validation for this input field.

Ex.
number of prints = 5
valid string: name1,name2,name3,name4,name5
valid string: name1,name2,name3

I load jquery-3.5.1.js and jquery-validation-1.19.2 in a page.

**Question 1:** How do I get the php $session['number'] in the rule "max_user_names: [numberofprints]" so it can be used in the max_user_name Method?

I think the actual validation can be done in 2 ways:

count the numbers of commas and if "number > numberofcommas" is true the string is valid
or:
split the string and count the values and if "number => numberofvalues" is true the string is valid.

**Question2:** Is one better than the other?

```
$.validator.addMethod('max_user_names', function(value, element, params) {
        return validationcode
    }, 'to many names');
    
    
    
$("#NamesModalForm").validate({
    rules: {
        user_names: {
            required: true,
            max_user_names: [numberofprints]
        },
    },
    messages: {
        user_names: {
            required: "Enter a value"
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After further reading I managed to fix it with the next code:

```
$.validator.addMethod('max_user_names', function(value, element) {
        var nameArr = value.split(',');
        var nameArrLength = nameArr.length
        return parseInt(nameArrLength) <= parseInt($("#quantity").val());

    }, 'to many names');
```